# How to wipe a git repository - or at least a branch - from the command line

Tags: git

Trying  to learn git and to say it is awkward.

Set up repository with master branch and then wanted to set up new branch. wanted to see how the version control from going from new branch to master.

```
(base) ➜  TimsGItGitHub git:(new) ✗ git checkout master
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
        .DS_Store
Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches.
Aborting
(base) ➜  TimsGItGitHub git:(new) ✗ git checkout new
M       .DS_Store
Already on 'new'
(base) ➜  TimsGItGitHub git:(new) ✗
```

I'm not sure what to do to just wipe the repository  and start again. I just want to go back to master and try again.

Comment: `git reset --hard HEAD` and then change the branch. With the caveat that this will wipe out all of your changes.

Comment: with `git checkout new`,  you are on a new branch called `new`  if you want to go back to master, `git checkout master`

Comment: beginner training for git and github https://skills.github.com/

Comment: @JeremyFiel: That’s the command attempted at the start of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You’ve committed [.DS_Store](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.DS_Store), which isn’t something you want to keep track of. First, delete it:

```
rm -rf .DS_Store
```

Then you can switch branches as you originally planned:

```
git checkout master
```

Make a commit that deletes the .DS_Store that was already committed to master:

```
git rm -r .DS_Store
git commit -m 'Remove .DS_Store'
```

Add the name `.DS_Store` your [*global* ignore list](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/ignoring-files#configuring-ignored-files-for-all-repositories-on-your-computer) so you won’t have the same problem in the future in *any* repository:

```
mkdir -p ~/.config/git
touch ~/.config/git/ignore
open ~/.config/git/ignore
```

Add the line `.DS_Store` to the end of the file and save.